# Which sentence structure is better?

Tags: grammar

Which sentence structure is better?

1. Completed his education at the Basic Vocational School for working
   people at the "ELWRO" Wroclaw Electronic Company in Warsaw in the
   profession of turner.
2. Completed his education at the Wroclaw Electronic Company Basic
   Vocational School for working people in Warsaw in the profession of
   turner.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think "working people" is part of the school's name, and should also be capitalized: Wroclaw Electronic Company's Basic Vocational School for Working People.  If this is for a resume, it may be better to include school's untranslated name (if the one you've provided is a translation), then the English name in parenthesis, because "for Working People" sounds a little strange at the end of the school's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the sentence a **subject**

He was trained as a turner and completed his education at the Wroclaw Electronic Company Basic Vocational School for working people in Warsaw.